# Visual studio 2012 - Code fit window breaking lines

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, shortcut

I pressed a shortcut of Visual studio 2012 but I don't know which one!

Now the code fits the dimension of the window.
So If I resize the window a long line of code is broken in 3 or 4 lines (only display, actually the code is in the same line).

The horizontal scroll bar cannot be used because a long line of code is split to fit the window size.

See the pictures:

**Before resize**
[image]

**After resize**
[image]

Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Press "Ctrl + E Then Ctrl + W"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have just activated **Word Wrap**

If it is the same as VS13 then `Ctrl + E` then `Ctrl + W` should fix it. Alternatively, in the Edit menu, go down to Advanced and the option should be in there.